# why HSSFWorkbook.write doese not work in HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, excel, jsf

I used below code to write a excel file in output stream. But when i open the downloaded file in excel it has problem with opening.

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = getWorkBook();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=someName.xls");
    response.setContentLength(workbook.getBytes().length);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    try {
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

of course i write the result in a File and it was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by removing below code.

```
response.setContentLength(workbook.getBytes().length);
```